# T-SQL: Query brings back too many columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ansi-sql

I've run across a query that seems to be bringing back too many columns (yes, columns, not rows).  The statement is below

```
Select TOP 10 PERCENT
       TempLegs.*,
       TMWStateMilesByLeg.*
From
(    
   Select  TOP 10
      TempOrigin.stp_city as 'Origin Location'
        from  stops TempOrigin (NOLOCK)
   Union
   Select  TOP 10
      TempOrigin2.stp_city as 'Origin Location'
        from  stops TempOrigin2 (NOLOCK)
) As TempLegs,TMWStateMilesByLeg
```

When I run this statement, my result set isn't a single column of 'Origin Location', but instead lists all the columns from the stops table. What's going on here?

The only thing that I can think of is that the

> As TempLegs,TMWStateMilesByLeg

statement is aliasing both pieces of the join, but I'm not sure as I've never see two terms in an AS statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The dot-star (.*) notation you are using tells T-SQL to display all columns of the given table.  So TempLegs.* would get you the single column you desire but the ",TMWStateMilesByLeg.*" is also going to give you every column in that table (of which I don't know what it is or how it factors into your query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is an old style join.

```
Select TOP 10 PERCENT /* <-- top without order by */
    TempLegs.*
       --,TMWStateMilesByLeg.* 
From (    
   Select  TOP 10 /* <-- top without order by */
      TempOrigin.stp_city as 'Origin Location'
        from  stops TempOrigin --(NOLOCK)
   Union /* <-- union instead of union all will return distinct results */
   Select  TOP 10 /* <-- top without order by */
      TempOrigin2.stp_city as 'Origin Location'
        from  stops TempOrigin2 --(NOLOCK)
  ) As TempLegs --,TMWStateMilesByLeg
```

Reference:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: My goodness.  Thank you for that, I would have never figured that out.  I didn't write this SQL by the way, I just stumbled across it trying to reconcile numbers from another system.  And yes, NOLOCK is everywhere!